# Google Maps V 3.8 and Touch Sensitivity for Draggable Markers

Tags: android, ios5, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Since I only have a restriction on V3 in my api registration:

The solution defaults to the latested. Today Google Maps API was updated to version 3.8.  Now my marker touch sensitivity on my iPAD 2 is a lot less sensitive.  I have to be exact before it recognizes the custom marker touched that has draggable:true.

When I set the library to V3.7 all is fine.

Is there something that I need to change in V3.8 to relax the sensitivity of marker objects to touch recognition?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is also in V3.9.  It happens when the `draggable=true` is set on a marker. It happens in iOS 5.1 and Android 3.2

See related post in Bugs.